# how to send sms to mobile from web application using asp.net and c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How do you send an sms message to a mobile phone from a web application using asp.net and c#?

Comment: Please, provide more details.

Comment: This question seems clear enough to me, and sufficiently small in scope to be answerable (unless it somehow requires pages of code to do this). I cleaned up the verbiage a bit, and upvoted.

Answer (score 6):

Most carriers provide an email suffix that can be used to send an SMS through email. Generally:

```
[PhoneNumber]@[Suffix]
```

You can contact individual carriers to get their suffix, but here is a list (Mostly North American carriers) to get you started:

```
Name                          Gateway
7-11 Speakout                 @cingularme.com
Alaska Communications Systems @msg.acsalaska.com
Alltel Wireless               @message.alltel.com
American Messaging            @amsmsg.net
AT&T Enterprise Paging        @page.att.net
AT&T Mobility                 @cingularme.com
AT&T Wireless                 @txt.att.net
BeepOne                       @beepone.net
Bell Mobility & Solo Mobile   @txt.bell.ca
Boost Mobile                  @myboostmobile.com
Cellular One                  @mobile.celloneusa.com
Cellular South                @csouth1.com
Centennial Wireless           @cwemail.com
Cingular                      @cingularme.com
Cricket                       @mms.mycricket.com
Fido                          @fido.ca
Globalstar                    @msg.globalstarusa.com
Helio                         @myhelio.com
Illinois Valley Cellular      @ivctext.com
Indiana Paging Network        @ipnpaging.com
Iridium                       @msg.iridium.com
MetroPCS                      @mymetropcs.com
MTS                           @text.mtsmobility.com
Ntelos                        @nteloswireless.com
Page1                         @page1email.com
President's Choice            @txt.bell.ca
ProPage Inc.                  @page.propage.net
Qwest                         @qwestmp.com
Rogers                        @pcs.rogers.com
Rogers Paging                 @paging.rogers.com
Sasktel                       @sms.sasktel.com
Shentel                       @shentel.net
Sprint (Nextel)               @page.nextel.com
Sprint (PCS)                  @messaging.sprintpcs.com
Suncom                        @tms.suncom.com
T-Mobile                      @tmomail.net
Telus Mobility                @msg.telus.com
Thumb Cellular                @sms.thumbcellular.com
Tracfone                      @cingularme.com
Unicel                        @utext.com
US Cellular                   @email.uscc.net
USA Mobility                  @usamobility.net
Verizon                       @vtext.com
Virgin Mobile (Canada)        @vmobile.ca
Virgin Mobile (USA)           @vmobl.com
```

<sup>A more comprehensive list can be found here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_carriers_providing_SMS_transit</sup>

This approach requires your users to specify their cell carrier when entering their number, but then you can send them texts for free (from your perspective) the same as sending an email in .NET.

As a side note, subject lines are not always interpretted correctly.  Most carriers just convert an email to sms like `[Subject] [Body]` but some discard the Subject completely.

There are also companies that provide this service (for a fee of course). The most obvious is [Twilio](http://www.twilio.com/sms/) but a quick Google search should find you some more.

Comment: Sort of explains the API, I guess, but doesn't really say much about how one would send an SMS message using code.

Comment: @Robert Harvey my answer answers the how (architecture) of the solution. Sending an email through code is pretty straightforward and can be found in multiple spots on SO and elsewhere so it didn't seem too relevant. In fact, if the OP doesn't feel like searching, @krtego's answer should fill in the gap just fine.

Comment: Ah, I see. Guess I didn't grok that it's just an ordinary email message.

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend [Twilio](http://www.twilio.com/).  You don't have to know which carrier your user has or worry about them switching carriers later on and them never receiving their texts.  With Twilio you can process more logic, like sending a text to ask a question and asking them to text back "y" or "n".  It can also be used to make phone calls.  There is support for C# and other languages as well.

However, each text costs a penny - so it is **not** free!
But if your requirements are such and pockets deep enough to handle penny-texts, then I'd recommend them.  I haven't found anything cheaper and they give you credit up front so you can test it out without costing you anything.  It's all pay-go, so if you have a $30 credit, you don't have to worry about seeing a $1,000 bill should you blow up everybody's beepers, or whatever the kids are using these days.

This is just another way to send texts that I have had a good experience with and feel is worth noting.
I know everybody prefers free.

Answer (score 2):

Building off theChrisKent's answer, you could send the email like this:

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");

mail.From = new MailAddress("your_email_address@gmail.com");
mail.To.Add("2128675309@cingularme.com");
mail.Subject = "Test Mail";
mail.Body = "This is for testing SMTP mail from GMAIL";

SmtpServer.Port = 587;
SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");
SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;

SmtpServer.Send(mail);
MessageBox.Show("mail Send");
```

If I recall correctly however, SMS sent in this fashion are not 100% guaranteed to show up (though it is likely)

Answer (score 0):

I used TcpClient, which implements Disposable & created SmsHelper 
    class

```
public class SmsHelper
{
    public void SendSms(string toNumber, string content)
    {
        bool connected;

        TcpClient smsServer = OpenConnection("xyz.xy.x.xyz", xyzd, out connected);//require ip and port

        if (connected)
        {
            string sms = content; 

            SendSmsToClient(smsServer, Properties.Settings.Default.FromNumber, toNumber, sms);

        }
    }

    protected static TcpClient OpenConnection(string ip, int port, out bool connected)
    {
        string response = string.Empty;
        string message = string.Empty;

        TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient();

        try
        {
            ASCIIEncoding ascEn = new ASCIIEncoding();

            tcpClient.Connect(ip, port);

            Stream stream = tcpClient.GetStream();

            byte[] bb = new byte[100];
            stream.Read(bb, 0, 100);

            string connect = ascEn.GetString(bb);

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(connect))
            {
                //authenticating to smsServer
                string str = "action: login\r\nusername: xxxxx\r\nsecret: integration\r\n\r\n";

                byte[] ba = ascEn.GetBytes(str);
                stream.Write(ba, 0, ba.Length);
                stream.Flush();

                byte[] resp = new byte[100];
                stream.Read(resp, 0, 100);
                response = ascEn.GetString(resp);
                stream.Read(resp, 0, 100);
                message = ascEn.GetString(resp);

                if (response.Contains("Success") && message.Contains("Authentication accepted"))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Authenticated");
                    stream.Flush();
                    connected = true;
                    return tcpClient;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Credentials error Cant Authenticate");
                    tcpClient.Close();
                    connected = false;
                    return tcpClient;
                }
            }

            connected = false;
            return tcpClient;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

        connected = false;
        return tcpClient;
    }

    protected static void CloseConnection(TcpClient client)
    {
        client.Close();
        Console.WriteLine("Connection Closed process terminated...");
    }


    protected static void SendSmsToClient(TcpClient client, string fromNumber, string toNumber, string smsBody)
    {
        string response = string.Empty;
        string message = string.Empty;
        string eventMsg = string.Empty;

        ASCIIEncoding asen = new ASCIIEncoding();
        Stream stm = client.GetStream();

        string smsSend = string.Format("action: smscommand\r\ncommand: gsm send sms {0} {1} \r\n\r\n", fromNumber, toNumber);

        byte[] smsCmd = asen.GetBytes(smsSend);

        stm.Write(smsCmd, 0, smsCmd.Length);
        stm.Flush();

        byte[] smsResp = new byte[1000];
        stm.Read(smsResp, 0, 1000);
        response = asen.GetString(smsResp);

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(response))
        {
            stm.Read(smsResp, 0, 1000);
            message = asen.GetString(smsResp);

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
            {
                stm.Read(smsResp, 0, 1000);

                eventMsg = asen.GetString(smsResp);

                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(eventMsg))
                {
                    String[] list = eventMsg.Split('\n');

                    foreach (string value in list)
                    {
                        if (value.StartsWith("--END"))
                        {
                            stm.Flush();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```