# Sms sending in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, mobile

I want to send sms from my asp.net web application to the mobile using gsm modem. For this purpose i want some dll file or api for sms gateway. For this purpose, when I browse the web then I found a .dll file on this link: http://www.intellisms.co.uk/sms-gateway/dotnet-component. I want to know can i use this .dll file with gsm modem and if yes then how? and if some one have any other sms gateway or api for .net application then please share with me.

Regards

Comment: this is a nice article: http://codeglobe.blogspot.com/2009/02/sending-sms-in-cnet-using-gsm-modem-and.html and also this article can inspire  you: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/SMS.aspx

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6113419/how-to-send-sms-to-mobile-from-web-application-using-asp-net-and-c and http://www.ozekisms.com/index.php?owpn=230

Comment: is there any reason why you want to send it via gsm modem?  i'm just curious.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using http://www.clickatell.com/ for a good time in a C#.NET WebForms app. Check if pricing fits your budget anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use that component. Create a new project and add the dll file as a .net object. In theire website they have a guide for the component and as far as I saw it is pretty straight forward. Just make sure your gsm modem is correctly installed and stuff lie that.

**Update:**

That website offers a paid membership service which will give a user & password to connect to theire sms service through that dll library.

Comment: how can i configure the gsm modem using this dll file because there is only option for username and password, there is no option for specifying port or any other details and i have very less know how of this procedure so please try to guide me.

Comment: Well on the second though...that library is about theire own service, you have to become a member and then they supply you with a username and password and then you can connect to theire gsm service. If you want to do it with your own gsm modem, please ignor my answer! If you get us to know what kind of modem are you using it will help more to answer your question. Also there should be some sort of manual with your modem that explains the installation procedures.

Answer (score 0):

I used an older version of the following dll few years ago.  http://www.activexperts.com/xmstoolkit/.  It worked great.  It seems to work better using modem that connect to serial port vs usb though.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [textmarks][1][1]: http://www.textmarks.com/ or [zeepmobile][1][1]: https://www.zeepmobile.com/ the provide a extensive set a methods and apis to integrated to send msm from a website.